# Generate code128 barcode with elaphe

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, barcode, ghostscript, eps

I use the [`elaphe` package](http://code.google.com/p/elaphe/) to generate a code128 barcode. However, the generated barcode is empty. At first I thought the problem was with ghostscript (used by the PIL library to read EPS files), but other barcode types work fine.

The code that I wrote is:

```
barcode('code128', 'barcodetest').save('/home/vj/barcodetest.jpg')
```

But it gives me `IOError: gs failed (status 256)` error.

What is the problem?

Comment: More information on this exact problem: http://code.google.com/p/elaphe/issues/detail?id=11

Comment: This is the tail of an error message, unfortunately you haven't quoted the actual error. Possibly the PostScript is broken, possibly its a Ghostscript bug. Its impossible to tell without seeing an example. I would also ask what version of GHostscript is being used ? If you are using an up to date version of Ghostscript (current is 9.06) you could open a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com where one of us can look at the problem. Don't forget to attach an example file which fails and give the Ghostscript command line.

Comment: Ah, I now see there is an example file attached to the google.com thread.

Answer (score 1):

The supplied PostScript file in the google.com thread is badly broken. I'm not certain if this is the actual original problem. Looking inside the PostScript file I see a number of technical problems, including the use of routines which are never defined (in fact many of these look like incorrect line breaks). However the most obvious problem is:

```
/rationalizedCodabar {
.....
.....
    /textsGS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>GS>ize 10 def
```

Clearly the repeated 'GS>' inserts should not be present, and the line should read:

```
    /textsize 10 def
```

I'm inclined to think the other problems I see are symptoms of the same fault. If this is the actual PostScript file being sent to Ghostscript, I'm not at all surprised it doesn't work.